# REST-Response not fully populated to js-object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I have a rest service to get information about persons. I also have an angular-app, where the information is displayed (and edited). The angular-app uses $q to get the information from the server, and if I directly look into the response I get the following information:

```
[{"data":{"id":12,"firstname":"John","lastname":"Milton","active":true},"status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://someurl/rest/persons/12","headers":{"Accept":"application/json"},"cached":false,"withCredentials":true},"statusText":"OK"}]
```

We can see, that the person has a firstname. Moreover, the firstname is also displayed in the input-box where I use  ng-model="ctrl.person.firstname". When I log the person to the console, it is also fine:

```
{id: 12, firstname: "John", lastname: "Milton", active: true}
```

But, when I just want to output the firstname on the form in a static way {{ ctrl.person.firstname }} it is empty.... and yet, again, when looking further into the objects I found:

```
Object {persons: Array[0], person: Object}
person: Object
active: true
firstname: undefined
id:12
lastname:"Milton"
__proto__:Object
persons: Array[0]
__proto__:Object
```

So, here we see that the firstname is "undefined". I had a few looks at my code, there is no single line which changes the firstname, and I'm stucked now.... and moreover - the form cannot be successfully submitted, because the inbox contains the firstname, but the validators didn't find the firstname...

And, what I first forgot to tell you: there are more than this one person, and on some everything works fine, and some fail like this one.

Here is the code which fetches the data and logs it (the output is shown above):

```
        angular.forEach(urls, function (url) {
            urlCalls.push($http.get(url.url));
        });

        $q.all(urlCalls)
            .then(function (results) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
                    console.log(results); ...
```

url.url is one (or more) urls to fetch.

Comment: Seems like a scope->template binding issue which can't be seen in the small amount of code you posted.

Comment: The "undefined" is already displayed in the person.service.js, which just loads the data from the REST-service. I don't see where there is some scope-issue. I also looked via Batarang into the issue, and there is the "firstname" property completely missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found the problem. After having some data in the database I added validators to the UI, and there is the problem. Min-Length (don't know why so short) is currently 5 -> John are 4 -> hence the ng-model=...firstname kicks the assigned value.